# How to draw simple line charts in excel with multiple dates for comparision

Tags: excel, charts, line

I have pasted a link which contains 2 images. One image is a sample list of data and other one is a sample chart I need.

https://picasaweb.google.com/116377794832905814061/ExcelQuestion?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCL_nksXwiNfXVg&feat=directlink

Can you please help?

Comment: Is this what you want to do ? http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/line-chart.html

Comment: Not really. If you see my sample data and sample chart, I want the dates to be on X axis & streams on the Y axis. The milestones should be on the chart lines based on the dates. Did u get it? Thanks

Comment: RIght, You just have to switch the axis around from the default. Or Try to make a Pivot first and use that for the chart, that would be easier.